# Recall attribute from an object

Tags: python-3.x, object

I am trying to figure out why I can't recall an attribute from a object. I'm sure I am making a simple mistake and hope this isn't a repeated question. Heres where Im at:

```
Class Vector:
    def __init__(self, cor_x, cor_y, cor_z):
        self.x = cor_x
        self.y = cor_y
        self.z = cor_z

    def x(self):
        return self.x
```

What I want:

```
v1 = Vector(1,2,3)
v1.x()
>>>1
```

What I get:

```
>>>v1.x()
>>>  TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I'm sure Im making a simple mistake somewhere.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have both the variable `self.x`, and a method `self.x()`: they clash. Since `self.x` is assigned to `cor_x`, which is the integer 1, you get the `TypeError` about an `int` object not being callable.

Make the variable(s) private (protected), and use the method as a property to return the variable.

```
Class Vector:
    def __init__(self, cor_x, cor_y, cor_z):
        self._x = cor_x
        self._y = cor_y
        self._z = cor_z

    def x(self):
        return self._x
```

Alternatively, you should just rename the method `Vector.x()` instead. Unless you really want to make `Vector.x` a full-blown property, in which case you wouldn't call it as a method, but simply access it like an attribute. That's a design decision that is up to you and requires a broader contextual knowledge of the code & project.

Comment: Thank you. I knew it was something that I was over looking. And yes there is more things to this class but I figured once I fixed this one thing, everything else would work. :)